# How to combine methods that have different objects as parameters

Tags: c#, .net

I've got two methods that look very similar, so I want to make one generic method. However, the parameters differ slightly. The first method requires two lists of `Event` objects and the second method requires two lists of `Entity` objects. Is there a way to combine the methods, despite the differences? I tried setting the parameter as `var` variables, but that didn't work. I've added the methods below:

First method:

```
public bool CompareEvents(List<Event> modelevents, List<Event> patternevents)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] eventproperties = typeof(Event).GetProperties();
        Event foundEvent = new Event();
        bool eventChecked = false;

        if (patternevents.Count == 0)
            return true;
        foreach (Event patternevent in patternevents)
        {
            foreach(Event modelevent in modelevents)
            {
                if (modelevent.Type == patternevent.Type)
                {
                    eventChecked = true;
                    foundEvent = patternevent;
                    for (int i = 2; i < eventproperties.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (eventproperties[i].GetValue(foundEvent, null) != null && eventproperties[i].GetValue(modelevent, null) != null)
                        {
                            string x = eventproperties[i].GetValue(foundEvent, null).ToString();
                            string y = eventproperties[i].GetValue(modelevent, null).ToString();

                            if (x != y)
                            {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        }
        if (eventChecked == true)
            return true;
        else return false;
    }
```

Second method:

```
public bool CompareEntities(List<Entity> modelentities, List<Entity> patternentities)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] eventproperties = typeof(Entity).GetProperties();
        Entity foundEntity = new Entity();
        bool entityChecked = false;

        if (patternentities.Count == 0)
            return true;
        foreach (Entity patternentity in patternentities)
        {
            foreach (Entity modelentity in modelentities)
            {
                if (modelentity.Type == patternentity.Type)
                {
                    entityChecked = true;
                    foundEntity = patternentity;
                    for (int i = 2; i < eventproperties.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (eventproperties[i].GetValue(foundEntity, null) != null && eventproperties[i].GetValue(modelentity, null) != null)
                        {
                            string x = eventproperties[i].GetValue(foundEntity, null).ToString();
                            string y = eventproperties[i].GetValue(modelentity, null).ToString();

                            if (x != y)
                            {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        }
        if (entityChecked == true)
            return true;
        else return false;
    }
```

Event Object:

```
public class Event
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Party { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string CommercialGood { get; set; }
    public string ChangeOfOwnership { get; set; }
    public string DirectionSubject { get; set; }
    public string AttributesSubject { get; set; }
    public string ToGroup { get; set; }
    public string Repeat { get; set; }
    public string PaymentRequired { get; set; }

}
```

Entity Object:

```
public class Entity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: If changing it to `var` was your attempt at solving this then it's clear that you would be best helped with a proper tutorial on C#. Answers to this question (though it has been asked many times before) would not be helpful to you. I suggest to start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/object-oriented-programming

Comment: What are the similarities and differences? This could work very well when Entity and Event share a base class or interface.

Comment: You need something in common, like either a common base class or a common interface. Do you have that? Or is it just that the *code* **looks** similar?

Comment: Or you can just do `public bool CompareObjects(List<object> list1, List<object> list2)` and then figure out which object is which. This *IS NOT* a proper way but still solves your problem.

Comment: @HenkHolterman They objects only have different properties. They do have some similar properties, such as `public int ID` and `public string Name` but the other properties differ. How could I solve it, if I gave them a shared superclass?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen the code looks similar. The objects differ in properties only. See my answer to Henk.

Comment: @Eric Tried it, didn't work: `cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Tool.Models.Event>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>`

Comment: An answer would depend on  what's in `{ [...] }`

Comment: Yes, if there's any commonality that can be usefully exploited here, it's in the bit you elided. At the very least you might be able to short-circuit on the arguments being the same object or on their having different sizes, but we can't even be sure of that.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I've added the rest of the code.

Comment: @JonHanna I've added the part that I had hidden before.

Comment: We still need to know about that `Type`  property. But it is starting to look like an X/Y question.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes, sorry. I've added the object classes, as well.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Thanks for your reply. I just carefully read the entire catalog of C# docs, tutorials, and guides. However, I didn't find the answer to my problem. Fortunately, others were able to help me here. See Henk's answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the edits, it seems you need to start with

```
interface IAmEventEntity { string Type {get; }}

class Entity : IAmEventEntity  { ... }
class Event : IAmEventEntity  { ... }
```

and then you can write

```
public bool CompareEventsOrEntities<T>(List<T> models, List<T> patterns)
    where T : IAmEventEntity  , new()
{
   T foundItem = new T();
   ...
}
```

but do consider AutoMapper to pump those properties over.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I make sure the right subclass is created in the method? Right now it is like this, for example: `Entity foundEntity = new Entity();`

Comment: I missed that, for 0 parameters it's easy. See edit.

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for are [generic methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods). These type of function is design to reduce redundant code cause of different data types.

example

```
public static bool Compare<T>(T entries)
{
    // ...
    return true;
}
```

test the function above

```
var t1 = new[] { "t", "t" };
var t2 = new[] { 1, 2 };

Compare(t1);
Compare(t2);
```